# How to dynamically poputate title and meta tags with php and/or javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to replace my title tag and meta description dynamically using parameters from a search query in PHP. They keep showing up blank, but if I echo the $title or $desc inside the original PHP (first set) of tags, it appears fine. There is no header.php file for reference.

```
<?php
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
list($chuck, $keep) = explode('?', $url);
$patterns = array(); 
$patterns[0] = 'foo';
$patterns[1] = 'bar';
$patterns[2] = '123';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = 'good ';
$replacements[1] = 'bad ';
$replacements[2] = 'ugly ';
$mytitle = "my cool " . $keep . " title tag";
$mydesc = "my cool " . $keep . " meta " . $keep . " description";
$title = str_replace($patterns, $replacements, $mytitle);
$desc = str_replace($patterns, $replacements, $mydesc);

//echo $title . "</br>";
//echo $desc . "</br>";
?>      
<title><?if (strpos($url, 'foo=') !== false) { echo $title . "</br>"; } else { some other title"; }?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $desc; ?>">
```

Alternatively, would a javascript/php mashup like this work?

```
<script>
    document.title = <?if (strpos($url, 'foo=') !== false) { echo $title . "</br>"; } else { some other title"; }?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to amend your title alteration code's else slightly to include echo "

```
<title><?if (strpos($url, 'foo=') !== false) { echo $title . "</br>"; } else { echo "some other title"; }?></title>
```

Other than throwing a parse error as is this seems to work fine for me.